# Group, count, having, and order by in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a table: `people` with a column named: `age`.

How can I get a count of the people with each age, ordered from oldest to youngest, filtered by ages with at least 2 people in it?

**How I would write it in raw SQL:**

```
SELECT
  COUNT(1) AS people_count,
  age
FROM people
GROUP BY age
HAVING people_count > 1
ORDER BY age DESC
```

**In Rails (I'm not sure how to do it):**

`Person.group(:age).count` will get me the counts by `age`, but I can't figure out how to order it descendingly by age, or add the `having` clause.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try something like:

```
Person.select("id, age").group(:id, :age).having("count(id) > 1").order("age desc")
```

Answer (score 13):

I find the other answers didn't work for me. I had to do something like this

```
Person.group(:age).having('count(*) > 1').order('age desc').count
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Person.select('COUNT(1) as people_count').order('age DESC').group(:age).having('people_count > 1')
```